# Date x axis in googleVis LineChart

Tags: r, datetime, google-visualization

I've been trying to get an x-axis to support a time using `gvisLineChart`. Trouble is, it's always interpreted as a character.

```
library(googleVis)
dat <- data.frame(time=as.POSIXct(c("2012-09-23 12:00:00", "2012-04-25 18:00:00", "2011-03-01 02:34:00")), 
                  x=rnorm(3), y=rnorm(3))


plot(gvisLineChart(dat))
```

How can I get the x axis to be properly interpreted as a date? I'm fairly certain `options=list(hAxis.format:"...")` is the solution somehow, but various formats including "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", but they don't seem to fix my problem at all.

In summary, I want a continuous datetime axis as suggested in possible in the [Google Chart Tools docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

Comment: I'm fairly certain correct usage of `options` would be `options=list(hAxis="{format:'M d y'}")`, but I don't think that's your problem - it's simply not seeing the date as continuous. As to why...

Comment: @alexwhan Sorry, typos. I'll fix those.

Comment: Can't work it out. Do you have an example anywhere of line chart with continuous date? As an aside, `gvisMotionChart` won't accept POSIX dates, but I've checked, and that's clearly not the problem here.

Comment: @alexwhan There is [this link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Help) which proves it is possible in Google Charts, but obviously doesn't directly help with googleVis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted the author of the package, Markus Gesmann, and he managed to solve the problem. The issue was that the CRAN version of googleVis (0.3.3) was not accepting date or datetime columns (in R, the POSIX and Date classes).

The following code does not produce the expected result under 0.3.3:

```
library(googleVis)
x <- as.Date(c(Sys.Date()+sample(1:100, 3)))

df <- data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"),
                 val1=c(1,3,4),
                 val2=c(23,12,32),
                 year=2011:2013,
                 num=c(1.2, 2.3, 3.4),
                 date=x)

Line4 <- gvisLineChart(df, xvar="date", yvar=c("val1", "val2"))

plot(Line4)
```

But it does produce a continuous time axis [under 0.4.1](http://code.google.com/p/google-motion-charts-with-r/source/browse/?r=364) which is the current development version.